# If $a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}$ then show that $ 3 | ab $

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

If $a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}$ then show that $ 3 | ab $

---

**Attempt**

I'll try by contradiction. If $3$ does not divide $ab$ then $ab = 3m + n$.

So we have 
$$ (a+b)^{2} = a^{2} + b^{2} + 2ab = a^{2} +  b^{2} + 6m + 2n $$
$$ a^{2}  + b^{2} = (a+b)^{2} - 2(3m + n) $$

how to show that $(a+b)^{2} - 2(3m + n)$ cannot be a square number?

Comment: Hasn't this question been asked before?

Answer (score 1):

If $3\nmid ab$ then $3\nmid a$ and $3\nmid b$ so $a^2\equiv 1\mod 3$ and $b^2\equiv 1\mod 3$. Hence 
$$c^2=a^2+b^2\equiv 2\mod 3,$$
which is impossible.

Comment: Why $c^2 \equiv 2 \ (\mod \ 3)$ impossible ? Because $c^2$ divided by $3$ can have $0,1,2$

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR If $c\equiv 0\mod 3$ then $c^2\equiv 0\mod 3$; If $c\equiv 1,-1\mod 3$ then $c^2\equiv 1\mod 3$.

Comment: here $c \equiv -1 (\mod 3)$ means $c \equiv 2 (\mod 3)$

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Yes. But $c\equiv -1\mod 3$ means $c=3k-1$ and so $c^2=3(3k^2-2k)+1\equiv 1\mod 3$.

Comment: yes you right. I am wrong. I got it now